# How to use awk to extract columns from a file based on a key?

Tags: sorting, awk

I have a file of keys, `file1`, (each key on a new line) that I need to use to extract certain columns from a second file, `file2`.  File 1 is 46 lines long, while `file2` is much larger, `>20,000` lines long.  Not all keys that appear in `file1` appear in `file2`, and vice versa.

file1:

```
322510472
322510472
322510472
322510484
322510484
322510484
322510493
```

file2:

```
109287879,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287879,148,1,148,NCVOG0391,0
109287880,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287880,458,1,458,,
109287881,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287881,156,1,156,,
109287882,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287882,451,1,451,NCVOG1423,0
109287883,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287883,217,1,217,NCVOG4910,2
109287884,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287884,494,1,494,NCVOG0211,0
109287885,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287885,447,1,447,NCVOG1077,0
109287886,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,109287886,347,1,347,NCVOG0967,2
```

Both `file1` and `file2` are sorted by the key, which appears in columns 1 and 3 of `file2`.

I need to produce a third file, `file3`, which contains my keys from `file1`, as well as columns 2 and 7 from `file2`, and which does not omit any keys present in `file1`, even if there are no matching entries in `file2`.

I know that I have 46 entries in my file of keys, `file1`.  However, when I use the following awk script,

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1 FS $2 FS $7; next} $1 in a {print a[$1],$2,$7}' file2 file1
```

I only see 44 lines of output.

I need to not delete any of my keys in my awk output, as they correspond to actual data I need to keep in other files also containing those keys.

Any suggestions?  Thanks for any and all help; I've been reading stack overflow for a while but this is my first time asking a question!

Comment: `$1 in a` condition will only be true for entries in both files, you need to print also the ones that didn't match.  If keys are unique, you can remove them from `a` after each match and iterate over the remaining keys in the `END` block.  You may want to sort the results afterwards as well.  However `join` is a better solution here since data is already sorted.

Comment: You need to provide sample data that actually can represent your problem

Answer (score 3):

your data doesn't have any matches, so I modified your keys to include matching entries

```
$ join -t, -a1 -o1.1,2.2,2.7 file1 file2

109287879,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,NCVOG0391
109287880,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,
109287882,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,NCVOG1423
109287884,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,NCVOG0211
109287886,Invertebrate_iridescent_virus_3,NCVOG0967
322510472,,
322510472,,
322510472,,
```

here is the file1 I used instead.

```
109287879
109287880
109287882
109287884
109287886
322510472
322510472
322510472
```